# How to display clicked user profile data in a different component?

Tags: angular, routes

I am quite new to angular and am trying to create a little app that utilises dynamic routing. I have a "members" page that lists all current members whereby if you click on one specific member you load another page used for displaying the user detail. Currently I am just trying to display "You have clicked on xxxs profile" but I am having trouble working out how to get the clicked user name displayed..

Member component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-members',
  template: `
    <li *ngFor='let members of members' (click)='onSelect(members)'>
      <span class='badge'>  {{members.name}} : {{members.id}}  </span>
    </li>
  `  ,
  styleUrls: ['./members.component.css']
})
export class MembersComponent implements OnInit {

  members = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Person 1'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Person 2'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Person 3'}
  ];

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSelect(members) {
    this.router.navigate(['/member', members.id]);
  }

}
```

I am at a loss as to how I should go about displaying the clicked profile name inside of the member component, anyone care to suggest a solution to me?

member component:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { ActivatedRoute, Params, ParamMap, Router } from '@angular/router';

 import { MembersComponent } from '../members.component';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-member',
  template: `
    You have clicked on {{  ****to be displayed****  }} profile!
   `,
  styleUrls: ['./member.component.css']
})

export class MemberComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with the above solution, you can pass the name in query params, if you don't mind the name in the URL..

Under Members component:

```
onSelect(members) {
    this.router.navigate(['/member', members.id], {queryParams: {name: members.id}});
}
```

Under Member component:

```
...
template: `You have clicked on {{memberName}} profile!`,
...

public memberName: string = "";
public subs$;
constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) ...

ngOnInit() {
    this.subs$ = this._route
        .queryParams
        .subscribe((params) => {
            this.memberName = params["name"];
        })
}

// this is to kill the subscription
ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subs$) {
        this.subs$.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can pass data into components, using EventEmmiters  **`EventReceiver`** **`@Input()`** or with a service.

In this case since you are using two independent (not parent/child) you should use service to **[`communicate between two components`](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)**